# Any reason why my ViewBag is not working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have following `ActionResult` in a `controller` and you can see that I set a message in the `ViewBag` if it's successful. Then on the `View` it should output that message if it's not empty. However, I can't get the message to display and I'm not seeing what the problem is.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                context.Roles.Add(new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole()
                {
                    Name = collection["RoleName"]
                });
                context.SaveChanges();

                ViewBag.ResultMessage = "Role created successfully.";
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return View();
            }            
        }
```

This is my Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Roles Listing </h2>

@ViewBag.ResultMessage

@Html.ActionLink("Create New Role", "Create") | @Html.ActionLink("Manage User Role", "ManageUserRoles")

<div>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped table-hover ">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Role</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var role in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>@role.Name</strong></td>
                    <td>
                        <span onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete @role.Name?')"><a href="/Roles/Delete?RoleName=@role.Name" class="delLink" style="color:red;">Delete</a></span> |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { roleName = @role.Name })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`ViewBag` helps to maintain data when you move from `controller` to `view`. Short life means value becomes null when redirection occurs. This is because their goal is to provide a way to communicate between `controllers` and `views`. It’s a communication mechanism within the server call.

Since you are using `RedirectToAction`, the `ViewBag` becomes `null` when it reaches the `view`.

you can use `TempData` for this:

```
TempData["ResultMessage"] = "Role created successfully.";
```

It uses `Session` as storage, but it will not be around after the second response.
`TempData` helps to maintain data when you move from one `controller` to other `controller` or from one action to other action. In other words, when you redirect, `Tempdata` helps to maintain data between those redirects. It internally uses session variables. `TempData` use during the current and subsequent request only means it is used when you are sure that next request will be redirecting to next view.

For more understanding on this refer this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476967/What-is-ViewData-ViewBag-and-TempData-MVC-Option)

Comment: WooW Really thank you. it helped too much for me Also

Comment: Thank you. I spent 3 hours trying to figure out why my stupid ViewBag was null.

Comment: Thank you for this. Could not figure out why my ViewBag & ViewData weren't working.

Answer (score 3):

> The ViewBag property enables you to dynamically share values from the
>   controller to the view. ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag%28v=vs.118%29.aspx))

It’s life lies only during the current request, and if redirection occurs then it’s value becomes null.
And since you using `RedirectToAction`, which redirects to some different controller, value of `ViewBag` is lost.

Consider using `TempData` instead.

```
TempData["ResultMessage"] = "Role created successfully.";
```

(See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/786603/Using-TempData-in-ASP-NET-MVC) for usage)

Comment: Thanks, as you can tell I'm still learning MVC and I'm just now doing a real world app with it which is why I have all these small issues pop up.

Answer (score 0):

The viewbag/viewdata scope is available for controller to view only. if you use tempdata, it will available  one request  , you can extend more than one request