# How can I set the selected value of a Html.DropDownList with viewbag

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my edit service page the selected value of DropDownList is not binding

```
@Html.DropDownList("ServiceID", ViewBag.Services as SelectList, "Select Service", new { @class ="form-control"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Code looks okay, I'm guessing that the **problem is in the Controller and not in the View**.

Assuming that you are passing in a `SelectList` into `ViewBag.Services`, then my best guess is that `ViewBag` is being reset, perhaps by a call to `RedirectToAction` which can be fixed by passing the data using `TempData` (instead of `ViewBag`) as suggested here:

[Any reason why my ViewBag is not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34447310/any-reason-why-my-viewbag-is-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

**View**

`@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Category as System.Collections.IEnumerable, "CategoryId", "Category_Name", Model.CategoryId1), "-- Select Category --", new { @class = "form-control selectmedium disableParent" })`

**Controller**

`ViewBag.Category = new CategoryBL().GetAllCategory();`